# Taking non-repeated values from a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm programming in Python. I have a variable `node` that takes the following values:

```
 node = (87.0921419983132, 106.6283716496173)
        (86.77840486780269, 97.63384170009026)
        (78.16407779475766, 95.02743246925114)
        (70.02882757413327, 91.17805539655082)
        (61.50050332176587, 88.30269708036101)
        (54.98537952281276, 82.09357782846105)
        (46.833207518576465, 78.2801683810838)
        (37.86736484348003, 77.49680057129092)
        (29.816754354836903, 73.47341011545032)
        (20.822013250759838, 73.78103402646268)
        (87.0921419983132, 106.6283716496173)
        (86.77840486780269, 97.63384170009026)
        (78.16407779475766, 95.02743246925114)
        (70.02882757413327, 91.17805539655082)
        (61.50050332176587, 88.30269708036101)
        (54.98537952281276, 82.09357782846105)
        (46.833207518576465, 78.2801683810838)
        (37.86736484348003, 77.49680057129092)
        (29.816754354836903, 73.47341011545032)
        (20.822013250759838, 73.78103402646268)
        (87.0921419983132, 106.6283716496173)
        (86.77840486780269, 97.63384170009026)
        (78.16407779475766, 95.02743246925114)
        (70.02882757413327, 91.17805539655082)
        (61.50050332176587, 88.30269708036101)
        (54.98537952281276, 82.09357782846105)
        (46.833207518576465, 78.2801683810838)
        (37.86736484348003, 77.49680057129092)
        (29.816754354836903, 73.47341011545032)
        (20.822013250759838, 73.78103402646268)
        (87.0921419983132, 106.6283716496173)
        (86.77840486780269, 97.63384170009026)
        (78.16407779475766, 95.02743246925114)
```

And so it is repeated indefinitely.

I need to create a list with the value of the first cycle since the repeated values ​​do not interest me.

I'm using

```
 lst = [node]
 new= []
 for i in lst:
     if i not in new:
          new.append(i)
          print new
```

But this returns and prints the same values ​​of the node variable.

What is my mistake?

Comment: This code is not valid Python. Please see [ask] and then provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is `node` a list of tuples?

Comment: This question is extremely difficult to understand. Perhaps you are looking for a set? `set(node)` This will enforce that each element is unique.

Comment: It seems your only mistake is that `print new` is inside the loop. Unindent it completely, and you will find that your code works. As @CopyandPaste says above, `set(node)` or `new = list[set(node)]` is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything right except print of new list which should be completely unindented as VBB pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, your code doesn't look like Python.

I presume your `node` variable is a list or tuple of tuples.

```
node = [(87.0921419983132, 106.6283716496173),
        (86.77840486780269, 97.63384170009026),
        ... ...]
```

In that case you can just create a "`uniq`'ed" tuple with

```
uniq_node = list(set(node))
```

if ordering is not important.

If you want to preserve the order as each item appears in the original sequence, you can try

```
seen = set()
uniq_node = []
for item in node:
    if item in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(item)
    uniq_node.append(item)
```

Worth mentioning is floating-point precision.  If you're sure you only want to remove duplicates at the bits level, this is fine. If you need to remove also the items that are close to seen ones, possibly due to numerical inaccuracy, this breaks.  In that case, you need to build a spatial tree and look for close neighbors instead of exact matches.